# Running CatBoost in Weka

Tags: weka, xgboost, catboost, rweka

Is there any way to run [CatBoost](https://catboost.ai/) in [Weka](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)?

Perhaps there is something similar to the implementation of [XGBoost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost): with the R-Pluging (MLR) or any unofficial package...

Weka is a wonderful tool, runnig Catboost on it could be great!

Comment: {mlr} is not an R Plugin but an R package. In addition it is deprecated and {mlr3} should be used.

Comment: Thanks, pat-s. In Weka (at least in v3.8.4) the only official package in the category "R integration" is called "RPlugin". In the "Package manager".

After the installation, algorithms appear in the "MLR" group. But there is no one for CatBoost.